# GIT Getting a branch from other repository

Tags: git, azure-devops

I had one repository (RepoA), this repo was duplicated for RepoB.

In RepoA exist a branch called featureX, I'd like  copy this branch to RepoB.

I'm using git in VSTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into `repoB`. Add a new remote with the url of `repoA` (say, repoA). Then just checkout `repoA featureX`.

```
$ git remote add repoA <repoA-url>  # add a new remote 'repoA' into 'repoB'

$ git fetch repoA               # fetch 'repoA'
$ git checkout repoA featureX   # checkout to repoA's 'featureX' branch
```

If you want to pull/merge `featureX` branch changes into repoB's current local branch:

```
$ git pull repoA featureX
```